# Laravel 5 Eloquent AND instead of where

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to get lists with filters like shown below, It doesn't work the way I want to.
In the `whereIn('lists.status', $status)`, It should return only lists where status is either 1,3 or 4. But it currently returns all lists without a specific status.

```
$status = [1, 3, 4];
$lists = List::query();

$lists->join("users", "users.user_id", "=", "lists.user_id")
      ->join('details', 'details.id', '=', 'lists.id')
      ->whereIn('lists.status', $status) <--- this is not working
      ->where('users.name', "LIKE", "john")
      ->orWhere('details.name', "LIKE", "john");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding a `orWhere` to end of your query which makes the query to return every row where `details.name` matches `john` regardless of the status.

Try following

```
$status = [1, 3, 4];
$lists = List::query();

$lists->join("users", "users.user_id", "=", "lists.user_id")
    ->join('details', 'details.id', '=', 'lists.id')
    ->whereIn('lists.status', $status)
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('users.name', "LIKE", "john")
            ->orWhere('details.name', "LIKE", "john");
    });
```

Comment: @ekclone it's like putting the last two `where` between parenthesis in a normal query

Comment: Oh my man you are a lifesaver, I've been trying to fix this for hours